# Is there a way to request Uber Connect through the Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

For users in metropolitan areas where Uber Connect is available, is there any way for a request for Uber Connect to be sent through an external app?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Delivery API (specifically the DaaS API): https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries